# How to set an absolute width for a bootstrap input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to set an absolute width for a bootstrap input :

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" min="1" max="31" id="date-naissance-register" placeholder="jj">
```

I want this input to have a 100px width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new class **at the end** of the bootstrap css file like this :

```
.form-width-absolute
{
width: 100px;
}
```

And add this class after the bootstrap class in your input in your html file :

```
<input class="form-control form-width-absolute" type="number" min="1" max="31" id="date-naissance-register" placeholder="jj">
```

It will erase bootstrap default width.

Comment: Don't modify bootstrap CSS files.  Create your own CSS file and load it after bootstrap...